# base 64 encoding and decoding for form security

Tags: php

I am coding a form that accepts input from users, i read in the net that using 
 `base64url-encode-decode`  will add a security layer to my form.

Please can any one tell me how to use them in my php processing page (sya that i have one text input named 'user'), as I didn't see any good and clear  example about using them effectively.

Comment: "will add a security layer to my form" --- that's bullshit.

Comment: if have some misconceptions or  made a mistake, correct it in a kind way. and watch your mouth. respect  comes first.

Comment: I don't think 'security' is the right term. base64 is just an encoding to encode special characters which are not supported by the protocol. It would be nice if you linked to the source of that statement, so we would have some context, because as you say it, it's incorrect (or 'bullshit' as some might say). I don't think you need to do this explicitly. Normally, if you make a form, the browser takes care of encoding it properly and PHP takes case of decoding it propertly. You shouldn't need to write anything special for this.

Comment: @Adam I deliberately used that word to express how nonsensical that statement is.

Comment: @GolezTrol I think I made a mistake since i am kind of new to  php. some one in another post suggested that if we want to print stored data in html attributes we use htmlspecialchars() together with urlencode(). so urlencode() is what I am talking about in fact

Comment: @zerkms, its ok men.

Comment: @Adam You need htmlspecialchars if you want to put a value in HTML (attribute or just content). `urlencode` is just for urls, so you don't need it for putting anying in html. For instance the text `'I said "Hello"!'` should be converted with `htmlspecialchars` if you want to put it in a title attribute. Doing that will translate the quotes to `&quot;`, so they don't interfere with the quotes of the attribute itself. Putting the text `'Hello World'` in an url, you would need `urlencode` to translate the space to `%20`. If you are building an url for a href attribute, then you need both.

Comment: Thanks every one. @GolezTrol thanks a lot for your good answer which is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious from what I've read so far that you indeed have a slight misconception of the concept of encoding/decoding, however, I would like to note that the layer of security which you are looking to achieve is very achievable with the means of a technique which is designed for that very purpose (encryption).

You see, the purpose of `encoding` information is not to hide it from others, but simply to reformat it in another way that may be more appropriate (e.g. base64 includes almost no special characters, may be better for data sent over JSON, e.t.c.)

The reason you can't really use encoding for this purpose is because all the encoding algorithms are very easily reversible, so the *only* thing one would have to do would be to write a miniscule bit of code that, instead of pulling out this information will pull it out and base64 decode it.

In a form in particular, the best way to really protect information that undergoes transit is the HTTPS protocol (which is also favourable to search engines so win, win).

If you still insist on having an extra `security layer` you can think of using `encryption` for this task, because the very purpose it was inflicted on this earth was to ***protect confidential information from being leaked/tampered with***.

**[Update]**
Another thing I would like to add is that when you protect information from someone, you should always keep in mind who is it you are protecting this information from. From what I gather, you are trying to prevent middle-man attacks. For preventing this I really recommend switching to HTTPS, because there really is almost no other way to protect data in form being transfered to a php page. If you are at some point interrested in protecting data sent from page to page (php), you can take a look at this [Really good post](http://code.runnable.com/UmmNdePavBUxAABZ/php-mcrypt-basic-encryption-and-decryption-of-a-string).

Cheers.

Comment: Good answer and a great first post. However, JSON is stored in unicode and could [contain (nearly) any character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_portability_issues), so that example might not be the best. Of course, if you want to transfer that UTF-8 encoded piece of JSON over some other protocol, you would have to re-encode the whole chunk in base64 or something alike.

Comment: @Samuel Allan thanks a lot for your time and the new information (for me )that you supplied